# How can i find the probability of a model classifying an input as [0,1]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am working on a classification problem in which i want to find the "probability of an input being classified as [1,0]" and "not [1,0]"

I tried using `predict_proba` method of SVC which gives the probability of class which I'm not looking for

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

model = SVC(probability=True)
model.fit(final_data,foreclosure_y)
results = model.predict_proba(final_data_test)[0]
```

I expect my output to be like this

```
index,y
---------    
0,0.45
1,0.62
2,0.43
3,0.12
4,0.55
```

Note: above output is in form .csv where y is the test_y

Here the column y is probabilities of each instance indexed from 0 to 4 that is could be classified as 0 or 1

For eg:- index 0 has probability 0.45 to be classified as 0 or 1

Comment: 1) what do you mean "gives the probability of class which i m **not** looking for"? 2) please **proofread** - "i am using using the wrong methos to calb=culate"?? 3) what do you mean (again...) the wrong methods? 4) what do you mean "[1,0] and not [1,0]" - please **show a sample of your `y`**

Comment: Thank you for your time and sorry u were not able to understand what i wanted to ask. Let me clarify, i want to find the probability of each instance of the dataset which can be classified as either 1 or 0 rather than the probability of class itself. Forget the predict_prob function

Comment: You sound a little confused; in your example, is there any **other** option for `index 0` except being 0 or 1?

Comment: Or is your output in fact an array of length 2? Please notice that I have requested a **sample** of your true `y` since you opened the question

Comment: Please notice that posting questions is not a fire-and-forget thing, and the best moment to post is **not** before going away for lunch/coffee/whatever. The first 20-30 mins are of great importance if you want to get your question answered, and you are expected to be available to answer to comments & clarification requests; From [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "*After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it.*"

Comment: I just want to predict the probability of classification for each instance

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Let me kindly suggest you go through the basic notions first so that you know what you are calculating; statements like "*i want to find the probability of each instance of the dataset which can be classified as either 1 or 0 rather than the probability of class itself*" sound meaningless, let alone "*Forget the predict_prob function*", which indeed does exactly what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

```
sum([0.58502114, 0.41497886])
# 1.0
```

`predict_proba` gives the probabilities for *both* your classes (hence the array elements sum up to 1), in the order that they appear in `model.classes_`; quoting from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict) (which are *always* your best friend in such situations):

> Returns the probability of the sample for each class in the model. The
>   columns correspond to the classes in sorted order, as they appear in
>   the attribute classes_.

Here is an example with toy data to illustrate the idea:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
model = SVC(probability=True)
X = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]] # feature vectors
Y = [0, 1] # classes
model.fit(X, Y)
```

Let's now get the predicted probabilities for the first instance in the training set `[1,2,3]`:

```
model.predict_proba(X)[0]
# array([0.39097541, 0.60902459])
```

OK, what is the order - i.e., which probability belongs to which class?

```
model.classes_
# array([0, 1])
```

So, this means that the probability for the instance belonging to class `0` is the first element of the array `0.39097541`, while the probability for belonging to class `1` is the second element `0.60902459`; and again, they sum up to 1, as expected:

```
sum([0.39097541, 0.60902459])
# 1.0
```

**UPDATE**

Now, in outputs such as the one you require, we don't put both probabilities; by convention, and for binary classification, we only include the probability  for each instance belonging to **class 1**; here is how we can do it for the toy dataset `X` shown above of only 2 instances:

```
pred = model.predict_proba(X)
pred
# array([[ 0.39097541,  0.60902459],
#        [ 0.60705475,  0.39294525]])

import pandas as pd
out = pd.DataFrame(pred[:,1],columns=['y']) # keep only the second element of the arrays in pred, i.e. the probability for class 1
print(out)
```

Result:

```
          y
0  0.609025
1  0.392945
```